# Swift : Checking if 2 NSDates are the same

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Really simple one, I am sure this is a bug in swift.  I am trying to check if 2 NSDates are the same.  This statement never passes even thought the printout is below

```
println("\(statistics.startDate) \(healthObject.date)")

if healthObject.date.isEqualToDate(statistics.startDate) 
{
      healthObject.flights =  Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
      println(Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())))
}
```

2015-03-30 13:56:50 +0000 2015-03-30 13:56:50 +0000

2015-03-30 13:56:50 +0000 2015-03-31 13:56:50 +0000

2015-03-31 13:56:50 +0000 2015-03-30 13:56:50 +0000

2015-03-31 13:56:50 +0000 2015-03-31 13:56:50 +0000

**Solution**
As pointed out by one the awesome people who replied, the dates are probably the same up until sub second level.  The odd part is, is these values are coming from **HealthKit**

What works for me in iOS8 is:

```
   if let dif = calender?.compareDate(statistics.startDate, toDate: healthObject.date, toUnitGranularity: NSCalendarUnit.SecondCalendarUnit)
   {
      println(Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())))
      println("\(statistics.startDate) \(healthObject.date)")
      healthObject.flights =  Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))

   }
```

Comment: Just tried very simple one and it seems to be possible to just NSDate() == NSDate()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to check if dates are equal is to use NSDate.isEqualToDate() method.

or

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(date1, toDate: date2, toUnitGranularity: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond)
```

If you are using quite a bit of date arithmetic check [this](https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/iDate) library.

Comment: I am using that but its return false, even though the print out shows they are the same

Comment: isEqualToDate() compares to sub-second level. I think your dates are different at sub-second level. If you want compare at higher level please check NSCalendar APIs. Specially NSCalendar.compareDate. I changed the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to compare NSDates with == operator (xCode 6.2). I tried the following simple compare

```
let startDate = NSDate()
var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()           
var calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
var endDate = calendar!.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: startDate, options: nil)

if(startDate == endDate) // true here
{
    println("equal")
}
```

if I change **endDate**

```
dateComponents.second = 5
endDate = calendar!.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: startDate, options: nil)

if(startDate == endDate) // false here
{
    println("equal")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension:

```
extension NSDate
{
    func isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare : NSDate) -> Bool
    {
        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
        {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }


    func isLessThanDate(dateToCompare : NSDate) -> Bool
    {
        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
        {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }


    func isEqualToDate(dateToCompare : NSDate) -> Bool
    {    
        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
        {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

the extension works fine check like:

```
var date1 : NSDate = NSDate()
var date2 : NSDate = date1.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-100)

print("\(date1)-----\(date2)\n")


if date1.isEqualToDate(date2) {
   print("date1 and date 2 are the same")

}else if date1.isLessThanDate(date2) {
   print("date 1 is less than date2")

 }else if date1.isGreaterThanDate(date2){
   print("date1 is more than date 2")
  }
```

and just change the value you add or subtract. Maybe you have to use a dateformatter for your dates

Answer (score 0):

I actually found this new method to fix the issue

```
let calender = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
if let dif = calender?.compareDate(statistics.startDate, toDate: healthObject.date, toUnitGranularity: NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit)
     {
         println(Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())))
         println("\(statistics.startDate) \(healthObject.date)")
         healthObject.flights =  Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))

     }
```

Comment: So actually you want to check if 2 NSDates are within the *same hour*, not if they are the same. It would be useful for future readers if you clarified that in your question.

Comment: No but this is a work around, it appears that the sub seconds could be different event though the times are via healthkit

Comment: NSDate represents an absolute point in time. If 2 NSDates differ by 0.01 seconds then they are different.